# SQL - Finding non-overlap days when comparing two tables of date ranges

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2018. I have two tables with date ranges. One of employee IDs and dates of employment and another of employee IDs and date worked. Everyone day of employment needs to have a corresponding date worked but I need to find the days of employment where there is no date worked.

```
Table 1    
Row, EmployID, EmployStart, EmployEnd
1   1   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
2   1   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
3   1   1/1/2018    12/31/2018
4   2   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
5   2   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
6   2   1/1/2018    12/31/2018              
7   3   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
8   3   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
9   3   1/1/2018    12/31/2018              
10  4   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
11  4   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
12  4   1/1/2018    12/31/2018              
13  5   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
14  5   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
15  5   1/1/2018    12/31/2018

Table 2
Row EmployID    WorkStart   WorkEnd
1   1   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
2   1   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
3   1   1/1/2018    12/31/2018  
4   2   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
5   2   1/1/2017    12/31/2017                      
6   3   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
7   3   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
8   3   1/1/2018    6/30/2018       
9   4   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
10  4   5/1/2017    12/31/2017
11  4   1/1/2018    12/31/2018
12  5   1/1/2016    12/31/2016
13  5   1/1/2017    12/31/2017
14  5   1/1/2018    12/31/2018
```

So in this data set, I want to call out rows 6, 9, and 11 of table 1 because there are dates of employment without dates worked. And then have the results be only the dates of not worked.

So the results would look like

```
Row EmployID    MissStart   MissEnd
1   2      1/1/2018    12/31/2018
2   3      7/1/2018    12/31/2018
3   4      1/1/2017    4/30/2017
```

I currently have this

```
select *
from table1 a
left join table2 b
    on a.employid = b.employid
    and (
        cast(a.employstart as date)between cast(b.workstart as date) and cast(b.workend as date)
        or cast(a.employend as date)between cast(b.workstart as date) and cast(b.workend as date)
        )
where b.employid is null
```

Comment: why you save those date as text instead of dates? Save it as dates so you can use index.

Comment: You might take a peek at this article also. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0):

Check for overlaps

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

```
select *
from table1 a
left join table2 b
    on a.employid = b.employid
    and (   cast(a.employstart as date) <= cast(b.workend as date) 
        and cast(a.employend as date) >= cast(b.workstart as date) 
        )
where b.employid is null
```